# Reactive Function Parameters

Tags: r, shiny

My goal is to make a reactive shiny function in R. There are multiple outputs (e.g. tables) which can be bind to a similar function. However I need the function to react on some parameter, specific to one table. Here is some simple sample code, which isn't working but it makes my idea clear - I hope:

```
output$tableOne <- DT::renderDataTable({
  getData(foo)
})

getData <- reactive(function(funParameter){
  corrStartDate <- input$StartDate
  corrEndDate <- input$EndDate

  return(someData(corrStartDate, corrEndDate, funParameter))
})
```

In all tables (if there is more then one) I wan't to show data with different base parameter (getData(x, y, foo)). So the second table could use "getData(x, y, bar)". I don't want to write every time the same function for another table.

The solution above is not working, since reactive functions do not support parameters.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 14):

This should work instead:

```
getData <- eventReactive(input$funParameter, {
  corrStartDate <- input$StartDate
  corrEndDate <- input$EndDate

  return(someData(corrStartDate, corrEndDate, input$funParameter))
})
```

`eventReactive` only updates if arguments stated up front change. Practically speaking, this reactive will not trigger if `input$StartDate` or `input$EndDate` changes.

If this is not what you want, normal reactive functions should work. I.e.:

```
getData <- reactive({

  funParameter <- input$funParameter
  corrStartDate <- input$StartDate
  corrEndDate <- input$EndDate

  return(someData(corrStartDate, corrEndDate, funParameter))
})
```

which will trigger if *any* of the inputs change